# Getting "Host "=" does not exist" when trying to automate file transfers using WinSCP script

Tags: command-line, sftp, winscp

I am trying to automate some file transfers using WinSCP scripting. This is what I have.

```
option echo off
option batch on
option confirm off
open abcde:abcde@sftp.xxxyyyzzz.net

lcd "t:\"

put -nopermissions -nopreservetime "test.txt" test.txt

exit
```

I can actually get to the command line and run the `open`, `lcd`, and `put` commands without any issue. When I use the script, I receive this error:

```
Opening session using command-line parameter in scripting is deprecated. Use 'open' command instead.
Searching for host...
Host "=" does not exist.
```

I got through the connection hurdle by putting the connection command in the batch file pulling the script.

```
Winscp.com abcde:abcde@sftp.xxyyzz.net
```

How do I call the script to run the rest of the tasks?

Answer (score 3):

You need to save your [WinSCP script](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scripting) to a file (e.g. `script.txt`).

And then make WinSCP run the script using [`/script=` command-line switch](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/commandline), like:

```
winscp.com /log=winscp.log /script=script.txt
```

You should start with a [guide to automating SFTP file transfers using WinSCP](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_automation).

Comment: /script= ... you saved me dude

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. I saved the following text as .bat file and ran it.

```
echo off
WinScp /ini=nul /command "open ubuntu@52.52.52.242 - 
privatekey=D:\PostgresXL.ppk" "move_files_or_do_something" "exit"
```